# How to use externalNativeBuild per productFlavors in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have two different versions of same app (free and paid) and using externalNativeBuild to build the native code. I do not want to include any native lib in the free version of the app. Is there a way to build the native code per flavor?
It gives me error "Could not find method path() for arguments  on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions" when I tried this

```
productFlavors {
    paid {
        applicationId 'com.example.paid'
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
            }
        }
    }
}
```